# Is it possible to ban an artist on Last.fm?

Tags: last.fm

Is it possible to ban an artist on Last.fm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. This has been a requested but unimplemented request for over three years:

- http://www.last.fm/forum/21717/_/380227/8